# ANTLR4 use ECMAScript.g4 target for python2 runtime to extract strings in JS file

Tags: javascript, python, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4

In my project,I use antlr4 to extract strings in javascript files.
I use the open source grammar ECMAScript.g4 file(the runtime is python2) and the url of this file is
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/ecmascript/Python

after running the g4 file with command:

> antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 ECMAScript.g4

I got several python files:lexer、listener、tokens and so on.
and in ECMAScriptListener.py I find a function enterLiteral

> def enterLiteral(self, ctx):

in this function I can get the strings, thus I add

> print 'text:',ctx.getText()

to test.
But I found that some files can be parsed correctly(all strings were printed),and some files(like jquery-3.1.1.min.js)will throw errors like

> line 2:200 rule returnStatement failed predicate: {!this.here(ECMAScriptParser.LineTerminator)}?
>
> line 2:250 missing ')' at ','

finally the strings before the error position will be printed,but the strings after the error position will not.I don't know why this happen and how to solve it.
(Sorry I have not learned compiler,but my project have to use antlr4)so I'm searching for help

Comment: If all you want are the string literals, you can just use the lexer without the parser. That way you'd avoid parse errors.

Comment: yes，I solved this problem by only using the lexer, judge the type of token, and the code is: if (token.type == ECMAScriptLexer.StringLiteral)